# Paginated HTML Sitemap

Tags: wp-query, pagination, loop, sitemap

I've got to the point where I needed to break down my HTML Sitemap into several pages. It contained 2000+ links.

The big layout was showing all post titles under category names on one page. I decided to break it down (paginate it) by alphabetical order using WP_Query, so each page would contain about 60 post titles (links). Also on every page beside the post titles, respective category links were shown and plus one other custom taxonomy.

I did it, and thought it will be OK, Google wise and Users wise. However soon after, I was bombarded with emails. Users were not liking the new paginated/alphabetical look of the HTML Sitemap. They wanted quick access to all posts from one page (or less number of pages as possible). I reverted back.

I can't keep that big page, but in the same time I have to go with the Users.

So, is there a way where I can split the HTML Sitemap into pages, and each page to contain posts titles (links) from several categories?

I can do this by creating several templates and hard-code the pagination on every template (link them), but that is the hard way.

I've looked into multiple loops, nested loops, custom queries, WP_Query, experimenting a lot but it seems I can't achieve what I want, in an elegant and clean way.

Comment: So what you're looking to do is list all the posts in a category and do a couple of those per page and have a few pages of that? If your userbase has said they don't like it, why change? Google's definitely not going to like it, you're raising the number of clicks to content.

Comment: Yes, list all the posts in a category and do a couple of those per page, and have a few connected pages. The change is because the page is to "heavy" to load and because Google will not definitely like it (2000+ links on one page).

Answer (score 1):

Haven't tested this, but here you go, lemmie know how it works. You'll needa do your own pagination links, but that should be pretty straightforward

```
//pagination
$offset = '0';
$no_of_posts = the_posts_per_page( false ); //Number of posts to display on each page
if (preg_match( '/page/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ) ) {
    $uri = explode( '/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] );
    foreach ( $uri as $key => $value ) {
        if ( $value == '' ) {
        unset( $uri[$key] );
        }
    }
    $offset = array_pop( $uri );
    $sql_offset = ( $offset * $no_of_posts ) - $no_of_posts;
}
//get categories
my_category_build( array(), 0 );

//function
function my_category_build( $args, $offset = 0  ) {

    //set defaults
    $defaults = array(
        'type'                     => 'post',
        'parent'                   => 0,
        'orderby'                  => 'name',
        'order'                    => 'ASC',
        'hide_empty'               => 1,
        'hierarchical'             => 1,
        'taxonomy'                 => 'category',
        'pad_counts'               => 1
    );

    //parse args
    $args = wp_parse_args( $args, $defaults );

    //do real work
    $categories = get_categories( $args );
    $cat_c = count( $categories );
    for( $i=$offset; $i<$offset+2 && $i<$cat_c; $i++ ) {
        //set current category object
        $categories[$i] = $cat;

        //drill down deeper
        $args['parent'] = $cat->cat_ID;
        $children = get_categories( $args );
        if( count( $children ) > 0 ) {
            my_category_build( $args );
        }

        //output posts from category
        $wp_query_args = array(
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'post_status'    => 'publish',
            'cat'            => $cat->cat_ID
        );
        $posts = new WP_Query( $wp_query_args );
        foreach( $posts as $p ) {
            //your output here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: OK thanks @m0r7if3r. I'll test this and let you know if it works.